# Regex matches in regexr but not in pythex nor in the python script

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match find out all possible instances of `--` between two Arabic sentences.

Here is my pattern for it:

`[\u0600-\u06FF]+--[\u0600-\u06FF]+`

Here is an example text:

`قَنَاتِيْ--وَ الْمُحَامِيْ`

It matches on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3h43a) but not on [pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5B%5Cu0600-%5Cu06FF%5D%2B--%5B%5Cu0600-%5Cu06FF%5D%2B&test_string=%D9%82%D9%8E%D9%86%D9%8E%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%90%D9%8A%D9%92--%D9%88%D9%8E%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%92%D9%85%D9%8F%D8%AD%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%90%D9%8A%D9%92&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Can anyone please help and let me know my mistake?

Comment: You can see [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5B%5Cu0600-%5Cu06FF%5D%2B--%5B%5Cu0600-%5Cu06FF%5D%2B&test_string=u--u%D9%82%D9%8E%D9%86%D9%8E%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%90%D9%8A%D9%92--%D9%88%D9%8E%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%92%D9%85%D9%8F%D8%AD%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%90%D9%8A%D9%92&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) that _Unicode_ is not available option on pythex. Why don't you try another site that knows what it's doing ?

Comment: @sin thanks, I found out my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my mistake in the python script.

I was prefixing the regex with `r` instead of `ur`.

After changing

`pattern = r'([\u0600-\u06FF]+--[\u0600-\u06FF]+)' #used in python 3`

to

`pattern = ur'([\u0600-\u06FF]+--[\u0600-\u06FF]+)' # used in python 2.7`